# CakePHP - gitignore

Tags: php, git, cakephp, version-control, gitignore

If I plan on deploying my cakePHP application on my server which automatically gets its files from git, should I delete the gitignore file? I do not want necessary files not being uploaded to my server, because then my application won't function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `.gitignore` file won't prevent a git repo to be updated (clone or pull).

And any important file should be:

- either versioned (and therefore pulled, *even* if that same file is in a .gitignore)
- or rebuild automatically